# php foreach Prints 2 times

Tags: php, foreach

the subject I do not understand is that "Hello" is printing once.
The other Foreach "Earth" prints twice. I don't understand where is the problem.

The Problem Eliminates When I Uninstall Foreach but it recurs when I type in foreach again

```
<div class="carousel-clip" data-jcarousel="true" style="width: 874.798px;">
<ul class="carousel-list" style="left: 0; top: 0;">
<?php foreach (YoutubeApi::getAllVideo('brhhkavxkgU') as $item): ?>
<p>Hello</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div><!-- end .carousel-clip -->


<div class="loop-content switchable-view grid-small" data-view="grid-small" data-ajaxload="1">
<div class="nag cf">
<?php foreach (YoutubeApi::getAllVideo('brhhkavxkgU') as $item): ?>
<p>world</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

```
class YoutubeApi
{
public static function getAllVideo($videoId)
    {
        $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos";
        static $all = [];
        $params = [
            'key' => '...',
            'part' => 'statistics,snippet',
            'id' => $videoId,
        ];

        $call = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $call);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $data = NULL;
        $data = json_decode($output, true);
        $all[] = $data;
        curl_close($ch);
        return $all;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. foreach <p> hello </p>
2. foreach
<P> world </ p>
<P> world </ p>
the result turns out like this. both are different topics. how can i fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your array `$all` is declared as static, which means that the second time it runs through, the first result is still there in the array. Each time you call the function, it will add the new result(s) to the `$all` array.

You need to clear the array each time, or not declare it as static in the function, if this is not desired behaviour.

Or, if it is desired behaviour but you want to display the results more than once, alter your calling code to retrieve the results, then foreach through them, rather than having the function call as part of the display loop.

Comment: Easiest way is to not declare it as static in the first place and just declare it as an array, and it will be automatically cleared each time the function is called. Or does it need to retain the results from the previous call?

Comment: No need to hold it can be deleted. when I delete static it still didn't work
Deprecated: Non-static method YoutubeApi::getAllVideo() should not be called statically in

Comment: Where are you removing `static`? From the function definition line, or from the array declaration line? I meant the latter.

Comment: public static function getAllVideo($videoId) edit public function getAllVideo($videoId) 
error Deprecated: Non-static method YoutubeApi::getAllVideo() should not be called statically in

Comment: have it logic does not have a logic, so when I call it clear the data

Comment: No, remove the static keyword from the __array__ declaration, _not_ the __function__ declaration. Instead of `static $all = [];` put `$all = [];`.